# I have this function call question in my sample exam it is for my finals and i would like to get your point for view

Tags: python

The question is to consider the following function definition:

```
def read_value_type(prompt='Enter a Boolean> ', convert=bool):
    val = input(prompt)
    return convert(val)
```

as a multiple choice:

1. `val = read_value_type(convert=bool, prompt='Enter a boolean>')`
2. `val = read_value_type(prompt='Enter a float> ')`
3. `val = read_value_type()`

and it is asked which of the above are valid calls to `read_value_type`?

Since none display errors, and seem to be reading, I was wondering whether the three of them would call the function or not?

Comment: How about trying them out? Fire up python in interactive mode and type it all in.

Comment: so i did but i just wanted to know if choosing all three of them as an answer would be wrong

Comment: Depends on whether your examiner has something other than `doesn't raise Exception` in mind with regards to `valid calls`

Comment: You can add `print "I'm called!"` line in your function to find out.

Comment: you should define what is "valid call" - call that produces no error? call that does right thing?

Comment: the question states "Which of the following are valid calls to read_value_type?" and that's it nothing more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them. But second will return bool, not float.